What does "..and make joyful the hearing of my wife with your approach" mean?
In Macbeth, Act 1, Scene 4, Duncan, the king, announces that Malcolm will be the Prince of Cumberland (and not Macbeth). Macbeth says that he'll go forward as a harbinger:

Duncan
[...]
We will establish our estate upon
Our eldest, Malcolm, whom we name hereafter
The Prince of Cumberland: which honor must
Not accompanied invest him only,
[...]
Macbeth
The rest is labor, which is not us'd for you:
I'll be myself the harbinger, and make joyful
The hearing of my wife with your approach;
So humbly take my leave.
Duncan
My worthy Cawdor!
Macbeth, Act 1, Scene 4, Amsco Literature Program edition

What does "..and make joyful the hearing of my wife with your approach" mean? If Macbeth had said my approach, I would understand this as meaning "I'll go be the harbinger and also go visit my wife, who will be glad to see me", which would fit with the "So humbly take my leave". However, he says your approach.
So what does Duncan's approach have to do with Macbeth's wife? Why would "the hearing of my wife" be made joyful with Duncan's approach? How does this fit into Macbeth's insincerity, given his next aside?
What's going on with this line?

At the end of the speech in which Duncan declares his eldest son Malcolm Prince of Cumberland (and thus his successor), he says they will go to Inverness, where Macbeth's castle is located. Since such a stay requires some preparation, Macbeth will go ahead to announce the arrival of Duncan and his staff and/or courtiers. This is the reason he gives for serving as the "harbinger".
"Harbinger" has a double meaning (both quoted from Wiktionary):

The familiar meaning of a "person or thing that foreshadows or foretells the coming of someone or something."
The now obsolete meaning of "One who provides lodgings; especially, the officer of the English royal household who formerly preceded the court when travelling, to provide and prepare lodgings."

The king and the unsuspecting audience would understand the second meaning, which is what Macbeth intends. Later, with hindsight (and possibly after the weird sisters' prophecies), we understand that the other meaning was also at play.
With the first meaning in mind, we understand that Macbeth wants the king to think that hearing about his (i.e. the king's) imminent arrival will rejoice his wife. The convolutedness of the clause is what signals his insincerity to the audience. (Macbeth's asides in Act 1, scene 3, e.g. the one starting with "This supernatural soliciting", had already taught us that he has things on his mind he does not want to share with the other characters.)
The disconnect between what Macbeth says and what he thinks is even greater in the first line of his speech: "The rest is labour, which is not used for you". "The rest" can both mean "what remains [to be done]" (i.e. remaining work or labour) or "repose" (i.e. the opposite of labour). G. K. Hunter's gloss (New Penguin Shakespeare, Penguin, 1967, page 145) provides the meaning that Macbeth wants to be understood:

it is wearisome to be inactive, when we know we ought to be doing something to serve you.

Nicholas Brooke (The Oxford Shakespeare, Oxford University Press, 1999, page 110) provides a somewhat similar gloss that sounds just as ingratiating:

resting would be a burden compared to serving you,

and adds that "'rest' and 'labour' interchange confusingly in 'which'". This comment hits the essence. What I think is happening here is not merely insincerity on Macbeth's part. It is more serious: the prospect of becoming king creates such a turmoil in his mind that he is at times unable to express himself in a way that is not confusing. This inner turmoil was first announced when Macbeth first heard the words, "All hail, Macbeth, thou shalt be king hereafter!" At that time, his reaction was so strong that Banquo asked, "Good sir, why do you start; and seem to fear / Things that do sound so fair?"
What we see in this scene is that even attempting to sound sincere is a challenge for Macbeth.

The question leaves out the lines that explain this:

DUNCAN: We will establish our estate upon
Our eldest, Malcolm, whom we name hereafter
The Prince of Cumberland; which honor must
Not unaccompanied invest him only,
But signs of nobleness, like stars, shall shine
On all deservers.—From hence to Inverness
And bind us further to you.
Shakespeare, William. Macbeth. c. 1606. I.iv.43–49. Accessed at folger.edu 11 July 2024.

Duncan has just said that he will be going to Inverness, which is Macbeth's castle. Macbeth therefore says he will go ahead of the king to let his wife know that the king is on his way. He says that Lady Macbeth will be glad to hear that Duncan is going to visit their home.
The line is ironic in a couple of ways. In the first place, Macbeth is being hypocritical, pretending to be a good servant to Duncan when in fact he's already hoping to supplant the king. Secondly, Lady Macbeth is indeed glad to hear that Duncan will be visiting Inverness, because she sees that the king can be murdered, and the throne usurped, during the visit.
